# Random Overwriting of Contacts key data creating duplicate records

Tags: civimember, contacts, contributions

Experiencing several instances of contacts names and email addresses being overwritten thus creating apparent duplication of their record.
The system is taking contact records whose First Name is the same as another contact and then overwriting the second contacts Last Name and Email Address. This effectively creates a duplicate record for processes such as mailing outs, renewal of memberships etc.
We have taken to taking a monthly copy of key details, searching for duplications then restoring any contacts data. This has happened with the same contacts on more than one occasion.

Another perhaps related instance is the system using another contacts name in the Source field in Contributions. For example our Treasurer updates membership payments (name Karen Baker) but in the Contribution record it shows Karen Aitcheson as the Source. The latter has no rights to access the system so how and why the system is picking her name is of concern.

Comment: What deduplcation rules do you have?  For the second part, it sounds like your CMS user to CRM contact mapping is messed up, possibly as the result of your first problem.  Which CMS are you using?

Comment: We are using Drupal as CMS. As far as I can tell we are using standard dedup rules. Certainly get warnings if trying to add and existing contact. To me it looks like a mapping issue but not sure how this can be resolved.